Trying to implement a PnL functionality to a trading/degen wallet portfolio tracker
gm guys, so I've been working on a code that's supposed to be able to track a wallet addresses and monitor and display the tokens it's currently holding and display the details of the tokens such as the mcap, liquidity, volume, token age, $ticker, balance. And then also displays the current PnL percentages of these tokens in the wallet from the moment it bought in and then also shows the initial amount of Solana used to buy in these tokens.
As you can imagine this has been a little bit tough, currently having issues mainly in getting the code to show the initial Solana used to buy and then calculate and continuously update the PnL values. Added a timer update function of 10 seconds to update all the details continuously but still doesn't show signs of working, anyway sorry for all the yap so see the code here, any input or help would be greatly appreciated (smiling with a single tear emoji):
import os
import json
import asyncio
import httpx
import base58
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Dict, List, Any, Optional
from decimal import Decimal
from dataclasses import dataclass
class WalletAddress:
"""Simple wallet address validator and handler"""
def init(self, address: str):
if not self.is_valid_address(address):
raise ValueError(f"Invalid Solana address format: {address}")
self.address = address
@staticmethod
def is_valid_address(address: str) -> bool:
    try:
        decoded = base58.b58decode(address)
        return len(decoded) == 32
    except Exception:
        return False

def __str__(self):
    return self.address

@dataclass
class TokenDetails:
address: str
name: str
symbol: str
price_usd: Decimal
price_sol: Decimal
market_cap: Decimal
liquidity: Decimal
volume_24h: Decimal
creation_date: Optional[int]
class SolanaInvestmentTracker:
def init(self, wallet_addresses: List[str]):
# Validate wallet addresses
self.wallet_addresses = [WalletAddress(addr) for addr in wallet_addresses]
self.client = httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=30.0)
self.investment_history = self.load_investment_history()
self.cache = {}
self.cache_ttl = timedelta(minutes=5)
self.last_cache_cleanup = datetime.now()
def load_investment_history(self):
    """Load existing investment history from file or create new."""
    try:
        if os.path.exists(CONFIG['INVESTMENT_TRACKING_FILE']):
            with open(CONFIG['INVESTMENT_TRACKING_FILE'], 'r') as f:
                return json.load(f)
        return {}
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading investment history: {e}")
        return {}

async def fetch_token_details(self, token_address: str):
    """Fetch token details with caching"""
    cache_key = f"token_details_{token_address}"
    if cache_key in self.cache:
        cached_data, cache_time = self.cache[cache_key]
        if datetime.now() - cache_time < self.cache_ttl:
            return cached_data

    try:
        # Fetch data from DEXScreener
        dex_response = await self.client.get(
            f"{CONFIG['DEXSCREENER_API']}/{token_address}"
        )
        dex_data = dex_response.json()

        # Fetch data from Jupiter
        jupiter_response = await self.client.get(
            f"{CONFIG['JUPITER_API']}?id={token_address}"
        )
        jupiter_data = jupiter_response.json()

        # Create TokenDetails object
        details = TokenDetails(
            address=token_address,
            name=dex_data.get('name', 'Unknown'),
            symbol=dex_data.get('symbol', 'N/A'),
            price_usd=Decimal(str(jupiter_data.get('price', 0))),
            price_sol=Decimal(str(dex_data.get('priceSOL', 0))),
            market_cap=Decimal(str(dex_data.get('marketCap', 0))),
            liquidity=Decimal(str(dex_data.get('liquidity', {}).get('usd', 0))),
            volume_24h=Decimal(str(dex_data.get('volume24h', 0))),
            creation_date=dex_data.get('createdAt')
        )

        self.cache[cache_key] = (details, datetime.now())
        return details

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching token details for {token_address}: {e}")
        return TokenDetails(
            address=token_address,
            name='Error',
            symbol='ERR',
            price_usd=Decimal(0),
            price_sol=Decimal(0),
            market_cap=Decimal(0),
            liquidity=Decimal(0),
            volume_24h=Decimal(0),
            creation_date=None
        )
        
# ... [previous code remains the same until SolanaInvestmentTracker class] ...

async def calculate_portfolio_pnl(self, wallet_address: str, tokens: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    """
    Calculate Profit and Loss (PnL) for tokens in the wallet.
    """
    pnl_summary = {
        'total_portfolio_value_sol': Decimal('0'),
        'total_investment_sol': Decimal('0'),
        'tokens': {}
    }

    wallet_investments = self.investment_history.get(wallet_address, {})

    for token_address, token_data in tokens.items():
        try:
            # Get token details and balance
            token_details = token_data['details']
            balance = Decimal(str(token_data['balance']))
            
            # Get investment info
            investment_info = wallet_investments.get(token_address, {})
            initial_sol_invested = Decimal(str(investment_info.get('initial_sol_invested', '0')))
            
            # Calculate current value in SOL
            current_value_sol = balance * Decimal(str(token_details.price_sol))
            
            # Calculate PnL
            pnl_sol = current_value_sol - initial_sol_invested
            pnl_percentage = Decimal('0')
            if initial_sol_invested > 0:
                pnl_percentage = (pnl_sol / initial_sol_invested) * Decimal('100')

            # Add token details to summary
            pnl_summary['tokens'][token_address] = {
                'symbol': token_details.symbol,
                'name': token_details.name,
                'balance': float(balance),
                'current_price_sol': float(token_details.price_sol),
                'current_price_usd': float(token_details.price_usd),
                'current_value_sol': float(current_value_sol),
                'initial_investment_sol': float(initial_sol_invested),
                'pnl_sol': float(pnl_sol),
                'pnl_percentage': float(pnl_percentage),
                'market_cap': float(token_details.market_cap),
                'liquidity': float(token_details.liquidity),
                'volume_24h': float(token_details.volume_24h)
            }

            # Update portfolio totals
            pnl_summary['total_portfolio_value_sol'] += current_value_sol
            pnl_summary['total_investment_sol'] += initial_sol_invested

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error calculating PnL for token {token_address}: {e}")
            continue

    # Calculate total portfolio PnL percentage
    if pnl_summary['total_investment_sol'] > 0:
        total_pnl = pnl_summary['total_portfolio_value_sol'] - pnl_summary['total_investment_sol']
        pnl_summary['total_portfolio_pnl_percentage'] = float(
            (total_pnl / pnl_summary['total_investment_sol']) * Decimal('100')
        )
    else:
        pnl_summary['total_portfolio_pnl_percentage'] = 0

    # Convert Decimal objects to float for JSON serialization
    pnl_summary['total_portfolio_value_sol'] = float(pnl_summary['total_portfolio_value_sol'])
    pnl_summary['total_investment_sol'] = float(pnl_summary['total_investment_sol'])

    return pnl_summary

def save_investment_history(self):
    """Save investment history to file."""
    try:
        with open(CONFIG['INVESTMENT_TRACKING_FILE'], 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.investment_history, f, indent=4)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error saving investment history: {e}")

async def track_initial_investment(self, wallet_address: str, token_address: str, amount_sol: float):
    """Track initial investment for a token."""
    if wallet_address not in self.investment_history:
        self.investment_history[wallet_address] = {}
    
    self.investment_history[wallet_address][token_address] = {
        'initial_sol_invested': amount_sol,
        'timestamp': datetime.now().timestamp()
    }
    
    self.save_investment_history()

... [rest of the code remains the same] ...
async def analyze_wallet(self, wallet_address: str):
    """Analyze a single wallet"""
    try:
        # Fetch wallet tokens using Helius API
        payload = {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "id": 1,
            "method": "getTokenAccounts",
            "params": [str(wallet_address)]
        }
        
        async with self.client as client:
            response = await client.post(
                CONFIG['HELIUS_RPC_ENDPOINT'],
                json=payload
            )
            data = response.json()

        tokens = {}
        for token in data.get('result', {}).get('value', []):
            mint = token['account']['data']['parsed']['info']['mint']
            balance = Decimal(token['account']['data']['parsed']['info']['tokenAmount']['uiAmount'])
            
            if balance > 0:
                tokens[mint] = {
                    'balance': balance,
                    'details': await self.fetch_token_details(mint)
                }

        # Calculate PnL
        pnl_summary = await self.calculate_portfolio_pnl(str(wallet_address), tokens)

        return {
            'wallet_address': str(wallet_address),
            'tokens': tokens,
            'pnl_summary': pnl_summary
        }

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error analyzing wallet {wallet_address}: {e}")
        return {
            'wallet_address': str(wallet_address),
            'error': str(e)
        }

Configuration
CONFIG = {
'HELIUS_RPC_ENDPOINT': 'https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=YOUR_API_KEY',
'DEXSCREENER_API': 'https://api.dexscreener.com/latest/solana/tokens/v1',
'JUPITER_API': 'https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/price',
'UPDATE_INTERVAL_SECONDS': 10,
'INVESTMENT_TRACKING_FILE': 'token_investments.json'
}
Main execution
async def main():
# Replace with your wallet address
wallet_addresses = [
'9g4R6dTZzERwYqVi4S5XzorT11U7bq48J6XcZmZM99MR'
]
tracker = SolanaInvestmentTracker(wallet_addresses)

for wallet_address in wallet_addresses:
    print(f"\nAnalyzing wallet: {wallet_address}")
    result = await tracker.analyze_wallet(wallet_address)
    print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))

if name == "main":
asyncio.run(main())
